# MySQL - Compare different key and values in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains keys and values for different users.

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| user_ID | key             | value |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U1      | steps_total     | 6     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U1      | steps_completed | 6     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U2      | steps_total     | 6     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U2      | steps_completed | 3     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U3      | steps_total     | 6     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| U3      | steps_completed | 5     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

I need to select 2 different keys but only compare their values to output whether the user has completed all steps.

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_ID | completed |
+---------+-----------+
| U1      | YES       |
+---------+-----------+
| U2      | NO        |
+---------+-----------+
| U3      | NO        |
+---------+-----------+
```

Because the keys and values are in the same row but separate columns, this makes it hard for my head to wrap around.

What query can I use to get a similar result?

Comment: why don't you store the course and the length in a separate table only once and link it to this table. Here you can record only the number of steps completed and then it will be easy to achieve what you want? Yours is not the best db layout for this task

Comment: @LelioFaieta I understand creating a separate table can solve so many of my issues, problem is this is a WordPress database and it is better not to touch it or it can break. The plan is to sync useful data from this WordPress database to another database.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for guidance. Is it now more of an minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: In a word. No. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    CASE o1.value = o2.value
        WHEN true "YES"
        ELSE "NO"
     END as completed
FROM
    users u
JOIN
    options o1 ON o1.user_id = u.id AND o1.key = "steps_total"
JOIN
    options o2 ON o2.user_id = u.id AND o2.key = "steps_completed"
```

Comment: Sorry you may have misread. I currently have the first table; the second table is what I am trying to get to output. Basically if the "steps_total" value is equal to the "steps_completed" value, then it will output a YES. So looking at the first table, only U1 has both key values equal to each other hence the YES in the second table. The other 2 don't have them equal to each other so it says a NO.

Comment: I meant this: you have one table `options` which includes some options for each users. You want to select 2 options and compare them for each users. The only assuption here is that you have `users` table, which you should have. What doesn't work here for you?